# Can't locate main in simple Scala Actor example

Tags: scala, program-entry-point, actor

project hello

...  // code as documented in similar threads on this topic

```
object Driver {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val system = ActorSystem("Main")
      val ac = system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor])
    }
}
```

In configuration, main class defined as main.  This was suggested in a previous post on this topic.

Error received at compilation: `Cannot locate main type "main" in project hello.`

Why doesn't the compiler see the main def?  I've tried using Driver.main and hello.main to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure you see this error during *compilation*, not running?

Comment: You are correct, it is the running state.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving out a lot of information here, but I guess your problem is that running in Eclipse does nor work, right? The problem then probably is that your source file is not in the directory it would need to be given its declared package name. Scalac accepts arbitrary packages within a given file, Java (and thus Eclipse) does not.

Comment: You are correct, this is within Eclipse.  I'm new to both Scala and Eclipse.  Any pointers to align the package name and source file to make Eclipse happy?  Thanks much!

Comment: This is automatically correct if you use the package explorer to create class definitions. Just never edit the `package` declaration of the generated files.

Comment: Ok.  Not sure what that means but I will explore.  Thanks!